# Unable to update columnDefinition of an existing column in Sharepoint list using graphApi - BadRequest error

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, columndefinition

Sample payload:

```
{
  "text": {
    "maxLength": 1000
  }
}
```

And my PATCH Url is
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/lists/my-list-id/columns/my-column-id

I am providing the usual headers
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
And
Authorization: Bearer Token....

I get BadRequest error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "One of the provided arguments is not acceptable.",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "badArgument",
            "date": "2023-01-30T16:34:49",
            "request-id": "b63137f9-fda0-41b7-9549-5952b5c89427",
            "client-request-id": "b63137f9-fda0-41b7-9549-5952b5c89427"
        }
    }
}
```

I tried adding "propagateChanges": true to the payload and I get slightly different error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-30T16:39:37",
            "request-id": "41ca6541-6097-45c6-9418-d1cf57272d2c",
            "client-request-id": "41ca6541-6097-45c6-9418-d1cf57272d2c"
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

NOTE: I am able to update for e.g. Description of the column, but not the text.maxLength property.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum length of a SharePoint *text* field type is 255, you cannot set it to 1000. If you try setting the max length to 200 for example instead of 1000, your query should succeed.

To allow longer strings, you have to use the "note" ("multiline text") field type, not "text". This one has a limit of 63,999.

I am not sure if you can change *column type* using graph api (you cannot as far as I remember, but I am not 100% sure), you may need to re-create that column as "multiline", change manually, use the classic rest api instead of graph api to do it programmatically, or something like a powershell script.

Comment: 1. "note" type is not allowed in graphApi columnDefinition. That is applicable only to Sharepoint REST api SPFieldType. @Nikolay not sure where you got that info.
2. 'text' type yes I am able to update to reduce the maxLength to say 200.
Its strange that graphApi doesn't let more than 255 chars length and doesn't have a  field type for it...

Comment: It is allowed. it's mentioned in the second answer how you do it with graph.

Comment: I am talking about updating the column length @Nikolay, with PATCH call. It is not reflecting the change in maxLength when I see the response, even though I don't get any error.

Comment: There are two types of text columns: "single line", that has length from 0...255, and its max length is defined by maxLength property, and "multiple lines" (aka "note") that always has maximum length 63.999 (and this max length is fixed and cannot be changed by user). You define the type of column you want (single line/multiple lines) when you create it and can't change it later using graph API. I think this clarifies it?

Comment: More about column types: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/0d8ddb7b-7dc7-414d-a283-ee9dca891df7

Answer (score 0):

If you have [textColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/textcolumn?view=graph-rest-1.0) and `allowMultipleLines` is set to `false` then you have `one line text` column and the maximum length is 255.

It's not possible to change column type from `one line text` to `multiple lines text` via Graph API.

Call

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/lists/my-list-id/columns/my-column-id

{
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": true,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 6,
        "textType": "plain"
    }
}
```

Will fail.

You have to create a new column and define it as multiple lines. Define `textColumn` and set `allowMultipleLines` to `true`.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/lists/my-list-id/columns

{
    "description": "",
    "displayName": "Column XXX",
    "enforceUniqueValues": false,
    "hidden": false,
    "indexed": false,
    "name": "My new multiple lines column",
    "readOnly": false,
    "required": false,
    "text": {
        "allowMultipleLines": true,
        "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
        "linesForEditing": 6,
        "textType": "plain"
    }
}
```

Comment: I created a column as
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/lists/my-list-id/columns
{
  "description": "col2",
  "enforceUniqueValues": false,
  "hidden": false,
  "indexed": false,
  "name": "col2",
  "text": {
    "allowMultipleLines": true,
    "appendChangesToExistingText": true,
    "linesForEditing": 3
  }
} 
works fine.

* So I tried update
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/my-site-id/lists/my-list-id/columns/my-col-id
{  "propagateChanges": true, "text": {
    "maxLength": 450,
    "linesForEditing": 4
  }
}
I get InvalidRequest error

Comment: @user428602 I think that you cannot set maxLength property if allowMultipleLines is true

Comment: FYI I had tried without allowMultipleLines prior to trying with... no dice

Comment: @user428602 So, now you want to set maxLength for multiple lines column? This is not possible even from Sharepoint UI (web). You can set maxLength only for one line text and the max value is 255

Comment: Then what's the point in having allowMultipleLines = true, setting @user2250152. if we can't update the column capacity. If we choose to change the length then we have to create a new column with greater length and copy the contents of the previous column and delete the previous column, in order to persist the older data. That's really a very inefficient way of doing things.